# image drag using javascript

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation, drag

I have an image which i don't want to drag but i want to get that effect.

for example :- I clicked on the image and without leaving the mouse if I moved the mouse over the whole screen. I don't want the image to move but a blur copy of image should move with my mouse.

regards,

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback

Comment: Hi Davin. Thanks for a quick response but is it possible using javascript

Comment: jQuery is a javascript framework. If you really want pure js then you could check out the source code. It's open source afaik

Comment: you dont want to try and implement that by yourself, by the time you work out compatibility issues with all browsers etc. they will all have published new versions and your testing will be rendered out-of-date, forcing you into an endless testing loop whereby by the time you fix all the bugs, there's a whole bunch of new ones. it is not recommended to reinvent the wheel, especially when a perfectly robust and flexible one already exists.

Comment: @davin I think you are overstating the issue of browser compatibility *by a long shot*. New browsers are not released every week, and when they are, these days, they tend to be more compatible with each other rather then less. And when you say "all browsers" I think you mean "IE and everything else". That's two. This is just another instance of "sure, it can be done, it is not that hard, but it is not 3 lines of code either, and it combines a few not-so-obvious concepts that would usually take a dedicated answer to explain. That's a lot of work, so here's a link, it is easier for both of us!"